# jqGrid: all rows in “inline edit mode” by default, save row data on focus out

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where a row is editable on click (i.e. 'editRow' inside 'OnSelectRow' works fine). But my requirement is to "load the grid with ALL ROWS IN EDIT MODE by default (Inline edit)", so there should not be any need for me click individual rows.

so i implemented following code:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this), 
    ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), 
    i, 
    l = ids.length;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        $this.jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
    }
}
```

but i cant save row data on focus out.can any one please suggest me a way to do it.

Comment: @Oleg please suggest me  a answer

Comment: I find - it's the wrong way to start `editRow` for all rows. You get a lot of problems, which you will have to solve later and the grid will work many slowly additionally. Why not to start it inside of `onSelectRow` callback for example? Alternatively you can use `formatter: "actions"` or `inlineNav` to add inline editing buttons in every row or the . Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) for example.